# How do I get the name used in the XML documentation for a .Net Type

Tags: .net, reflection, xml-comments

I have an API project that uses .Net's XML documentation. This results in `MyApp.dll` getting a `MyApp.xml` file with all the code comments, which looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>MyApp</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="T:MyApp.MyNamespace.MyClass">
            <summary>Description of class</summary>
        </member>
        <member name="M:MyApp.MyNamespace.MyClass.MyGenericMethod``1(``0)">
            <summary>Description of method</summary>
            <typeparam name="T">Description of generic type</typeparam>
            <param name="paramName">Description of parameter.</param>
            <returns>Description of what this returns.</returns>
        </member>
        ...
    </members>
</doc>
```

I have `typeof(MyClass)` and from that I want to extract all this documentation. I know that I can use SandCastle to build an external .CHM help, but this needs to be part of the application that uses the API.

I want to be able to use XPath `$"//member[@name='key']"` to get the relevant `XmlNode` in the documentation file.

It's fairly easy to look up `typeof(MyClass)` or even use `typeof(MyClass).GetMembers()` to get the members, but there doesn't appear to be an easy way to get the name used in the XML documentation. For a type I can use `$"T:{typeof(MyClass).FullName}"`, but for `MemberInfo` this is a great deal more complicated, especially for generics. Every parameter [must be included in the lookup key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsbx0t7x.aspx).

I can read the `MemberInfo.MemberType` and parse all the generic and regular parameters, but that seems like a lot of work for something .Net must already be doing to build the XML file in the first place.

So, I have the `MemberInfo` for `MyGenericMethod` - how do I get ``` "M:MyApp.MyNamespace.MyClass.MyGenericMethod``1(``0)" ``` from that?

Comment: Maybe give SAX parser a try ? would that of some help here ?

Comment: @ZygoteInit it's really not parsing the XML that's the problem - I have a bunch of options there (that's why I haven't tagged this as XML). The problem is that the comments XML (or any other format that I turn it into) refers to member names by a complex `string` key that I can't easily parse from the `MemberInfo`.